# How Can I Align my texts with my header image?

Tags: html, css, format

I have an image header used in an automatic reply Email system, How can I align my text to the image?

**Here is how it looks like:**

[image: Text not align with the image]

**Source Code:**

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img alt="" src="myImage.png" /><br />

  <p style="font-family: arial;">Dear [Test Text],<br />
    <br /> Today’s Doodle celebrates Jordan’s Independence Day and 74 years of freedom. On this date in 1946, the country now known as the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan became a sovereign nation. ​ <br /> While that day hasn&#39;t arrived yet, we are committed
    to understanding our employees&#39; perspectives on how COVID-19 has impacted the way we work, and this will help inform how we will move forward together.<br />
    <br /> Illustrated in the Doodle artwork, the flag of Jordan features the traditional pan-Arab colors of crimson, black, green, and white with a seven-pointed star that symbolizes the unity and strength of the Jordanian people.
    <br />
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That tutorial can be useful for you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `<p>` in a `<div>` and give it an inline style like this:

```
<div style="width:500px;">
  <p style="font-family: arial;">
    Today’s Doodle celebrates Jordan’s Independence Day and 74 years of freedom. On this 
   date in 1946, the country now known as the Hashemite Kingdom of Jord
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to have the text auto-align to the image instead of putting a fixed margin to the right?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to have the image-size be dynamic? He's not making the margin 500px. He's just making the div containing the text match the 500px width of the image.  Then, both elements just automatically float to the left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

To really answer your question thoroughly, I recommend learning about the CSS box model, in order to understand how all of the elements behave.

1. Here, I made a container div and set its width to 90% of the parent container. You can also set it to a fixed measurement, like 500px.  Now, all of the divs that are inside it will stretch to fill it's width, by default.
2. Then, I put a div inside of that container div.  It moves to the top of the container div and automatically matches the width of the container.  It will not have any height automatically, so I set a random height (which you can adjust).
3. Then, instead of using an img tag, I made the banner image into a background image of this div. (I recommend looking up background-size property to learn how to size the background image).
4. Next, take out all of the `<br>` tags. They're not good practice for because they're hacky and don't give you good access to styling your content. Instead, put each paragraph in its own `<p>` tag.
5. To center the container div on the page, you can use the style "margin:auto." That makes the left and the right side have an equal margin. If you don't want it to be centered, take that out and put "float:left" in the style.
6. To see how all of the div tags are acting, put a "border:solid purple 2px" on them with different colors.

```html
<div class="container" style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
  <div alt="" style="background-image:url('https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/00/02/44/5056179b42b174f.jpg');height:3rem;border:solid blue 1px;background-size:cover;">the image is the background of this div</div>
  <p style="margin-bottom:1rem">Dear [Test Text],</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:1rem">
    Today’s Doodle celebrates Jordan’s Independence Day and 74 years of freedom. On this date in 1946, the country now known as the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan became a sovereign nation.
  </p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:1rem">
    While that day hasn&#39;t arrived yet, we are committed to understanding our employees&#39; perspectives on how COVID-19 has impacted the way we work, and this will help inform how we will move forward together.
  </p>
  <p>
    Illustrated in the Doodle artwork, the flag of Jordan features the traditional pan-Arab colors of crimson, black, green, and white with a seven-pointed star that symbolizes the unity and strength of the Jordanian people.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the text to align next to the image? You can use `float: left` style to the image.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" style="float: left" />

  <p style="font-family: arial;">Dear [Test Text],<br />
    <br /> Today’s Doodle celebrates Jordan’s Independence Day and 74 years of freedom. On this date in 1946, the country now known as the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan became a sovereign nation. ​ <br /> While that day hasn&#39;t arrived yet, we are committed
    to understanding our employees&#39; perspectives on how COVID-19 has impacted the way we work, and this will help inform how we will move forward together.<br />
    <br /> Illustrated in the Doodle artwork, the flag of Jordan features the traditional pan-Arab colors of crimson, black, green, and white with a seven-pointed star that symbolizes the unity and strength of the Jordanian people.
    <br />
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```